# How to use CSS import in Liferay? CSS fast load works bad

Tags: html, css, import, liferay

I found, that my CSS imports just does not work.

The beginning of my `custom.css` file looks following:

```
@import "compass";

@import url(fonts.css);

@import url(custom_common.css);

@import url(journal-content-article.css);

@import url(color_schemes/green.css);

@import url(color_schemes/orange.css);
```

Unfortuantely, I see no signs of (for example) `fonts.css` in Chrome Developer tools.

**UPDATE**

I found, that this relates with date-time modified issue when deploying.

I found, that

1) physically `tomcat6/mytheme/css/custom.css` file DOES contain my include directives.

2) when accessing `http://mysite/mytheme/css/custom.css`via browser, I see NO include directives, but SOME include directives are processed server-side. Simultaneously, the CONTENT of inclusions made is OLD, i.e. does not contain files, laying nearby.

Why?

Who performs server-side import? Probably this piece of software does not notice that include files are renewed!

3) when accessing `http://mysite/mytheme/css/custom.css?css_fast_load=0` I SEE the import directives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're doing this in your theme.

Make sure to do this for example to your custom.css, located in your theme's docroot/_diffs/css folder. AFAIK the import statements have to be before any other css statements in order to be processed.

Also, make sure that you have a file named docroot/_diffs/css/fonts.css that has some valid markup. Start extremely simple.

I've just tried this, abusing the "fonts" file for simple background color: Here's my files:

docroot/_diffs/css/custom.css:

```
   @import "compass";
   @import url(fonts.css)
```

docroot/_diffs/css/fonts.css:

```
   body { background: green; }
```

This will render a "_styled" theme (as I didn't change anything else) with green background instead of the default white.

Edit:
As your update states that you can't see changes to your files: Be aware that Liferay caches the minified results. If it doesn't pick up changes, you might need to delete the caches which are located in tomcat's temp folder AFAIK (if you use tomcat)

Comment: I found that import is processed server-side in Liferay, and this is what is glitching.

Comment: updated the answer: You might need to delete caches, e.g. temp files

Comment: shouldn't any cache system check the date-time if working correctly?

Comment: it depends: Checking time implies overhead and on a production system it's safe to assume that files will not arbitrarily change. You can have the same for jsps: Tomcat is configurable to check the jsp timestamps or not for recompiling. And if you're on a nonproduction system, Liferay has the development settings that don't cache at all.